# Trying to overlay one div above another

Tags: html, css

Here in this code I am trying to overlay one navigation bar (*content1*) above another (*content*), but nothing seems to be working. What am I doing wrong? Even if I can make it overlay, they are not placed centered within the container.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
}

#content1 {
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.container .nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 100px;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.search {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.90;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 390px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="logo">Google</div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>Feedback</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div id="content1">
    <div class="logo">Google</div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>Feedback</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just want to know how to overlay my nav bar above another nav bar and make it center within the container,

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to overlay over what?

Comment: I am trying to overlay the <div id="content1"> over <div id="content">

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right you need to change the `z-index` property of `#content1` and add `position:absolute`.

If the element has an absolute position, its position will not depend on the position of the other element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position )

If two elements are on the same location on the screen, the element with the highter `z-index` property will be displayed ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index )

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
width:100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
}

#content1 {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.container .nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.search {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.90;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="logo">Google</div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>Feedback</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div id="content1">
    <div class="logo">Google</div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>Feedback</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In their question one of the objects already has it's position set to absolute. I believe setting both of the container's position this way might not be the most efficient way to tackle this. One of the containers has a stable position, as such only one of the two should have it's position modified.

Comment: @ichinator i tried your code now the div is not center of the container its in the left side, how can i make the  <div id="content"> center inside the container ?

Comment: Why do you want to center #content and content ? Doesn't it take the entire width of the container ?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Since the two objects are already inside a container, they inherit a z-index from their parent. If you just have two, reordering them is simple enough.

I believe it is easier to send one of the two containers to the background that layer them on top of one another.
Since you are trying to overlay the second container over the first, the first one should have its position set to `absolute`.
With this done, it would suffice to set the first container to have `z-index: -1;` and the second one any *non-negative* value.

This should work:

```
#content {
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
#content1 {
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

### Solution 2

A better way to tackle this problem it to wrap both navbars inside a container and initially setting them up as identical using classes.
Then, simple modify the position of the navbar you want to overlay using `position: absolute;`.

Here is a rough example of how it should look:
**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="wrap">
  
    <div id="content" class="contents">
      <div class="logo">Google</div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>Feedback</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="content1" class="contents">
      <div class="logo">Google</div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>Feedback</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>test</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
}

#wrap {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.contents {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}

#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I would like to note that after reading @Ichinator 's answer that the `position: absolute;` property might have played a vital role in this working. I will update my answer to include this!

Comment: But <div id="content"> is disappeared !

Comment: <div id="content"> went back of container and moved to the left

Comment: @Solomondavid By setting `position: absolute;` you remove all positional references of that object. In essence, it has an independent position on the screen.
I think if you remove the background color of the `.container` the first container should show up again.
In the end, it might be better to set both positions to absolute use the parent container as a reference for position and scale. I will update my answer to include an alternative solution.